# Understanding a basic assembly code with lea instruction

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have the following snippet which at the end of it I need to specify what is the value inside `%rbx`.

```
.global _start
.section .data
array: .long 0xf415, 0xf3561768, 0x8200f645
a: .short 1
b: .quad 0x670081b521c
.section .bss
.lcomm stam, 4
.section .text
_start:
xor %rcx, %rcx
xor %rax, %rax
xor %esi, %esi
lea array, %rbx
```

Since I am a total beginner in assembly, I want to try and break down the code line by line to test my understanding of it and I would love it if you could correct my mistakes.

`.global _start` states that our program starts to run from label `_start`.
`.section .data` states that we enter an initialization of "variables" section.
`array: .long 0xf415, 0xf3561768, 0x8200f645` initialize an array of longs with 3 values `0xf415, 0xf3561768, 0x8200f645`
`a: .short 1` initializes variable a with one bit value of `1`.
`b: .quad 0x670081b521c` initializes variable b with 64 bit value of `0x670081b521c`
`.section .bss` declaration of other variables without initialization
`.lcomm stam, 4` declares variable `stam` and stores 4 bit for it.
`.section .text` declaring a read-only section.

```
_start:
xor %rcx, %rcx
xor %rax, %rax
xor %esi, %esi
```

starting the main program and initializes to 0 registers `rcx, rax, esi`.
`lea array, %rbx` - I am having a hard time understanding how is the effective address is calculated here since `array` has 3 values (if my assumptions were right)

EDIT:
<s>Does `lea array, %rbx` "translate to" `%rbx = 0xf415 + (0xf3561768 * 0x8200f645)` ?</s>

EDIT:
If it is given that the start of the data sections in memory is `0x601038`, does it mean that `lea array, %rbx` "translates to" `%rbx = 0x601038`?

Not sure it is relevant in this case but I am working on a processor that uses little-endian.

Comment: `array` is just the symbol / label address.  Bytes you assemble into the output (e.g. with a `.long` pseudo-instruction) *after* that label can't affect its address.  Also, never use LEA this way; either use `mov $array, %ebx` if you want 32-bit absolute addresses, or use `lea array(%rip), %rbx`.  [How to load address of function or label into register in GNU Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)

Comment: so the `array` symbol address is the start of the `.data` section, whatever that is.  It's not an assemble-time constant; it would be set at link-time if linking into a non-PIE executable, otherwise not even then.

Comment: it's bad idea to strart assembler research with a protected mode task. run dosbox-x with masm

Comment: @PeterCordes regarding the LEA usage, I'll keep this in mind (it is not a code I have written it is a part of an hw assignment).  
Also, could you confirm my edit? did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин : Strongly disagree with that suggestion.  Real-mode is an extra level of complexity (segmentation), and non-orthogonal register addressing modes.  32-bit x86 is closer to the direction modern ISAs are evolving towards: a bunch of mostly non-special registers, farther from 8-bit micros.  DOS itself is also basically useless, with different system calls than modern OSes. See also the beginner section at the top of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, and my [Suggestions on how to learn asm, with a recommendation against 16bit DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34918617)

Comment: but i didn't talk about real mode. you can do sector sized pm os to start with or make pm switch   in dos exe  .  is it possible without dos/bios knowledge is another question . you should know bios at least

Comment: @PeterCordes   assembler outside real mode and os development.... `Due to restricted access...`   http://nicolascormier.com/documentation/sys-programming/os-programming/CPU_Rings_Privilege_and_Protection_Gustavo_Duarte.pdf     that's it

Comment: Your understanding of `.global _start` is incorrect.  This directive tells the assembler that `_start` is a global symbol.  Nothing more, nothing less.  It does not set the entry point of the program.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: Oh, right, you did say protected mode, not DOS just DOSBox.  IMO learning how to do OS development for x86 (notoriously complex) at the same time you're learning asm at all is a big mistake.  Anyone that understands C already understands how user-space works: OS gives you space for your code + data, you use it.  Learning the basics of asm in that sandbox in a modern OS with a flat memory model makes it much easier to *then* learn about segment registers, GDT / IDT, and all that stuff if/when you ever choose to.  (Not to mention the emulated legacy device IO ports.)