# MUL function in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, multiplication

I am trying to execute simple multiplication in Assembly.  However, I do not see the registers change when the `MUL` function is called.

```
mov bx, 5    
mov cx, 10

mul cx
```

Comment: AX and DX will change, unless they happened to contain the result already.  When an instruction doesn't do what you expect, read the manual.  http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html

Comment: `mov bx, 5` ==> `mov ax, 5`

Comment: It's called an «instruction»

Comment: Related: [problem in understanding mul & imul instructions of Assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1948058) / [MUL instruction doesn't support an immediate value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4529260) re: multiply by a constant (as an immediate) with `imul bx, bx, 10`

Answer (score 72):

These are called *instructions*, and they specify *operations* that are to be performed by the processor. `mov` is a mnemonic for *mov*e, while `mul` is a mnemonic for *mul*tiply. Other common instructions include `add`, `sub`, and `div`. I trust you can figure out what operation these specify!

Most instructions take two parameters. In the technical jargon, these are often known as *operands*. The first (on the left) is the *destination*, and the second (on the right) is the *source*. So, in the case of `mov bx, 5`, this moves the literal value `5` into the destination register `bx`. The order of these parameters matters, of course, because you could not move the contents of the register `bx` into the literal value `5`!

The `mul` instruction is a little bit strange because some of its operands are implicit. That is, they are not explicitly specified as parameters. For the `mul` instruction, the destination operand is hard-coded as the `ax` register. The source operand is the one that you pass as a parameter: it can be either a register or a memory location.

Therefore, you could imagine that `mul cx` means `mul ax, cx`, but you don't write it that way because the `ax` destination register is implicit.

Now, a `mul` instruction commands the processor to multiply the destination operand by the source operand, and store the result in the destination. In code, you can imagine that `mul cx` would translate into `ax = ax * cx`. And now you should see the problem: you have not initialized the contents of the `ax` register, so you are multiplying 10 (which is the value you placed in `cx`) by whatever garbage was left in `ax`. As such, the result is meaningless!

If you in fact want to do 5 * 10, then you just have to change one character in your code:

```
mov  ax, 5     ; ax = 5
mov  cx, 10    ; cx = 10
mul  cx        ; ax = ax * cx   ; actually dx:ax = ax * cx
```

The result will be stored in `ax`, which is the implicit destination register.

Well, technically, the result will be stored in `dx:ax`. This is a *register pair*, and means that the high portion of the result will be stored in `dx`, while the low portion of the result will be stored in `ax`. Why this extra complication? Because multiplying two 16-bit values may result in a value that is larger than 16 bits! Returning the full multiply result in a *pair* of 16-bit registers allows the `mul` instruction to return a 32-bit result. When you're just learning, though, you don't need to worry about this. You can just ignore the possibility of overflow, and extract the low portion of the result from `ax`.  (But remember that 16-bit `mul` overwrites `dx` whether you want it or not.  On 386 and later you can use `imul ax, cx` to really do `ax *= cx` without wasting time writing `dx`.)

And while I'm sure that this is just a toy example, there is really no reason to write *code* that multiplies two constants together. This can be done at build time, either using a calculator and hard-coding the value, or writing out the multiplication of the constants symbolically and letting your assembler do the computation. That is, `mov  ax, 50`. Or let your assembler do it for you with `mov ax, 5 * 10`.  But like I said, I'm sure you knew this already!

If all else fails, do consult the documentation for the instruction that is giving you trouble. You can almost always find this online by Googling the name of the instruction and "x86". For example, the `mul` documentation can be found [here](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html), as well as several other sites. This information can be kind of complicated, but with a bit of effort, you should be able to extract the information you need. You will also find lots of other great information and links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

> but for some reason i do not see the registers change when the MUL function is marked.

I should also point out that, if you are using a debugger to step through your code, the currently marked/highlighted line is the line that is *about* to execute. It has not executed yet, so its effects on registers, memory, etc. will not be visible yet. You have to step over the instruction, so that the mark/highlight is on the *next* line, and then you will see the effects of the previous (just-executed) instruction.

If you understood my explanation above, after a `mul` instruction, you should see the contents of the `ax` and `dx` registers change. You will also see flags and the instruction pointer change, if your debugger shows either of them. Nothing else should change!  (Intel's instruction reference manual [entry for `mul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul) doesn't list any other effects on the architectural state of the machine.)

Comment: Great answer. Also worth noting; the resulting product will zero out the high-order register, even when the product is small enough to fit in the first of the two registers holding the product.

Answer (score 6):

The `mul` instruction has 2 operands: one is specified and the other one is implicit.

When you write `mul cx` it means something like: `ax = ax * cx`.

Actually it means `dx:ax = ax * cx` - the high half of the full 32-bit product is always written to `dx`.  `dx` will be zero for small products where the result "fits" in `ax`.  If you only want the low 16 bits of the result, you can just think of it as destroying `dx`<sup>1</sup>.

The answer of your question, if you really want to multiply 5 with 10, you can do something like this:

```
  mov  ax, 5   ; ax = 5
  mov  cx, 10  ; cx = 10

  mul  cx      ; dx:ax = ax * cx
; So   ax = ax * cx
; and dx=0 because the product happens to be small.
```

---

**Footnote 1**: 186 allows `imul dst, src, constant` like `imul ax, cx, 5`, allowing any registers with no implicit use of AX or DX.
386 allows `imul reg,reg` non-widening multiply with no implicit registers.
https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul covers both forms.

Of course if you can use 386 features, you'd use `lea` instead of `imul` to multiply by 3, 5, or 9, using 32-bit addressing modes that allow a scaled index (i.e. built-in shift count).

```
  mov  ecx, 10
  lea  ax, [ecx + ecx*4]
```

Comment: *if the product is greater than 16 bits*.  No, the full 32-bit result is *always* stored in dx:ax, whether you want it or not.  For small results that means DX is zeroed.  Your phrasing implies that small results would leave DX unwritten, but that isn't the case.  For that, you need 386 `imul ax, cx` to do a non-widening multiply (only the 16-bit low half).  Or 186 `mov cx, 10` / `imul ax, cx, 5` to do `ax = cx*5` using an immediate source.  (Or 386 `lea ax, [ecx + ecx*4]` to multiply by 5 more cheaply.)

Comment: Thanks, for your comment. I'll attach it as a note.

Comment: Easier and better to just describe it accurately the first time, instead of adding a correction.  I made an edit that I think is just as easy to read, but doesn't imply anything that needs correcting.